# Nested json array

Tags: ios

```
{
"m:mGetControlPanelResponse": {
    "count": "0",
    "pushMessage": [{
        "message": [{
            "rightColor": "#ff0000",
            "left": "Variance Alert :",
            "leftColor": "#000000",
            "messageId": "0",
            "right": "12.5%"
        }, {
            "rightColor": "#ff0000",
            "left": "Performance :",
            "leftColor": "#000000",
            "messageId": "1",
            "right": "1.BudLight<br/>2.yungling<br/>3.Guinnes<br/>"
        }, {
            "rightColor": "#ff0000",
            "left": "Temparature Alert :",
            "leftColor": "#000000",
            "messageId": "2",
            "right": "cooler1: 45<br/>Cooler2:36<br/>"
        }],
        "ltype": "1",
        "location": "425",
        "type": "1",
        "date": "2015-04-05"
    }, {
        "message": [{
            "rightColor": "#ff0000",
            "left": "Variance Alert :",
            "leftColor": "#000000",
            "messageId": "0",
            "right": "12.5%"
        }, {
            "rightColor": "#ff0000",
            "left": "Performance :",
            "leftColor": "#000000",
            "messageId": "1",
            "right": "1.BudLight<br/>2.yungling<br/>3.Guinnes<br/>"
        }, {
            "rightColor": "#ff0000",
            "left": "Temparature Alert :",
            "leftColor": "#000000",
            "messageId": "2",
            "right": "cooler1: 45<br/>Cooler2:36<br/>"
        }],
        "ltype": "1",
        "location": "976",
        "type": "1",
        "date": "2015-04-06"
    }, {
        "message": [{
            "rightColor": "#ff0000",
            "left": "Variance Alert :",
            "leftColor": "#000000",
            "messageId": "0",
            "right": "12.5%"
        }, {
            "rightColor": "#ff0000",
            "left": "Performance :",
            "leftColor": "#000000",
            "messageId": "1",
            "right": "1.BudLight<br/>2.yungling<br/>3.Guinnes<br/>"
        }, {
            "rightColor": "#ff0000",
            "left": "Temparature Alert :",
            "leftColor": "#000000",
            "messageId": "2",
            "right": "cooler1: 45<br/>Cooler2:36<br/>"
        }],
        "ltype": "1",
        "location": "970",
        "type": "1",
        "date": "2015-04-07"
    }]
}
}
```

Hi I want to sort this with date and use the right key values in the samecell.Suggest any idea

Comment: Please add code which you have tried..!

Comment: I want to display the data of right in a tableviewcell. Im getting the array of values for key right is 12.5%"1.BudLight<br/>2.yungling<br/>3.Guinnes<br/>""cooler1: 45<br/>Cooler2:36<br/>". I want to display it in different label in a singlecell.

Answer (score 0):

It's not very clear what you are asking. You posted a data dump of some fairly complex JSON. It's a little hard to sort out what is what just looking at it.

Use NSJSONSerialization to read it into Cocoa Foundation objects (dictionaries and arrays of strings. Then examine the structure that you've got.